# Post & edit a post from front end along with upload, dropdown, and other inputs

Tags: posts, theme-development, front-end

I am following this [tutorial](http://voodoopress.com/2011/03/review-of-posting-from-front-end-form/) to post from front end. I am able to post the title, content, category, tags, I would like to know is it possible to add more fields like in the image below. How to increment field-set? and how to add edit the post from the front end itself?

basically this what I want to do.
[image: front end post with advanced fields]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is better if you use the ajax method instead of sending the POST to the same page.

You can use javascript to increment the form / fieldset. Use an array for the name e.g

```
<input type="text" name="ingredient[]"/>
```

If you want to edit the post, just you us the saved data on the value attribute, e.g

```
<input type="text" name="ingredient[]" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ingredient[0]', true) ?>"/>
```

If the post meta using a same meta_key, just put it in the for each loop.

Hope this help